# Hide all DL elements except one

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup for a simple accordion [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/avBLQr):

```
<dl>
  <dt class="link">dt 01</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 01</dd>
  <dt class="link">dt 02</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 02</dd>
</dl>
```

And I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('dl').children('.pane').hide();
  $('dl').children('.link').bind('click', function(event) {              
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                 
    $(this).next('.pane').toggle().toggleClass('active');
  });  
});
```

When a dt is clicked the next dd opens and both get the CSS class "active".

But when a DT is clicked I would like to hide any dd that is currently open and remove its active class ... How can I do this?

I am having problems in selecting all the DL which is not the one after the DT that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** in this case

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('dl').children('.pane').hide();
  $('dl').children('.link').bind('click', function(event) {
    $('.link.active').not(this)
      // not for avoiding clicked dl
      .toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('.pane').toggle().toggleClass('active')
      .siblings('.pane')
      // get sibling dd
      .hide();
     // hide them
  });
});
```

```css
dl {
  width: 200px;
}
dt {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
}
dd {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0;
}
dt.active:after {
  content: '\f068';
}
dt:after {
  color: #606060;
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
dd.active {}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt class="link">dt 01</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 01</dd>
  <dt class="link">dt 02</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 02</dd>
  <dt class="link">dt 03</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 03</dd>
  <dt class="link">dt 04</dt>
  <dd class="pane">dd 04</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: That worked! I tried siblings before but I must did something wrong. Thank you for the help.

Comment: To fast ... in fact didn't work. Check this updated pen: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/avBLQr. When I click one item to open and click it again to close the icon does not change back to + ... I have no idea why.

Comment: On the example in http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/avBLQr click twice on the same DT. The next pane opens and closes ... But when it closes the icon on the right does not change back from - to +. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, the same problem on your example. Click twice on the same DT ... you will see that it opens and closes but when it closes the - is not replaced by +

Comment: @Miguel : updated , use `not()` to avoid clicked object

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now. Going to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Miguel : glad to help you :) :)

Answer (score 2):

On click, Simply remove *all* `.active` class instances, then add it only for event target, as needed.

```
$('select all dds')
    .removeClass('active')
    .next('.pane')
        .removeClass('active');

$(this).toggleClass('active');
$(this).next('.pane').toggle().toggleClass('active');
```

**Update**: my mistake, I hadn't seen you wanted to *hide* the dd's also. So the code (you can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzhn899r/)) would be:

```
$('dl').children('.pane').hide();
$('dl').children('.link').bind('click', function(event) {              

    $(this).parent() /* Get the parent DL */
       .find('.active') /* find all active objects */
           .removeClass('active') /* deactivate them */
           .filter('dd') /* find the DD's in there */
               .hide(); /* Hide them. */

    /* Now show this one. */
    $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .next('.pane').addClass('active').toggle();
  });
```

Also, if you want to be able to **re-close** a dd:

```
  var alreadyActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

  $(this).parent() /* Get the parent DL */
       .find('.active') /* find all active objects */
           .removeClass('active') /* deactivate them */
           .filter('dd') /* find the DD's in there */
               .hide(); /* Hide them. */

  /* Now show this one, if it wasn't active before */
  if (!alreadyActive) {
      $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .next('.pane').addClass('active').toggle();
  }
```